# Is it possible to display the XZ or YZ grid besides the current XY grid?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, interface

Is it possible to display the XZ or YZ grid besides the current XY grid?

The side view grids would help in calculating and modeling.

Comment: I've undoubtedly misunderstood what you're asking, but are you wanting what you get when you Toggle Quad View by either clicking View->Area->Toggle Quad View, or by pressing CTRL->ALT->Q?

Comment: @curious_1 Hi. That's a cool idea, but I simply want to get a XZ or YZ grid besides the default XY grid. Open your normal perspective view, you only see the XY grid on the floor, right? Now I want a similar grid but in XZ or YZ coordinate system.

Comment: I think they're only available in orthographic camera mode when viewing the model directly from the X, Y or Z axis

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you. So there's no solution to this, it seems.

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done :). I've seen some workarounds using nodes and textures, but never tried it myself.